# Using Amazon MWS as an e-commerce solution

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm currently looking into using Amazon Marketplace Web Services (MWS, https://developer.amazonservices.com/) as e-commerce solution for a client's website.

We will be putting this client's products on Amazon, the questions I have about MWS I have are as follows:

- Is it possible to pull products from an Amazon Seller Account onto a non-Amazon seller website using MWS?
- Is it possible to submit orders for those products on the non-Amazon seller website and have Amazon do all the payment processing and shipping?
- Following the previous question, would it be possible to receive shipping updates for products customers order through this non-Amazon seller website?

I have been reading the MWS documentation and overview pages and it seems like MWS might be able to do everything I need, I just thought it would be nice to receive verification from someone who has worked with MWS before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ethankar a few month later, did it work out as you expected? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to pull products from an Amazon Seller Account onto a non-Amazon seller website using MWS?

**Yes.** You can use MWS to "download" data from Amazon. I haven't done that myself (all integrations I've done are the other way around), but it seems, that there may be [considerable lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285686/how-up-to-date-are-amazon-mws-reports) if you do this through the reporting API.

> Is it possible to submit orders for those products on the non-Amazon seller website and have Amazon do all the payment processing and shipping?

**Yes.** For payment processing, look at [Amazon's payment solutions](https://payments.amazon.co.uk/developer/documentation) which are not part of MWS. Shipping can be done through MWS using the FBA (Fulfillment by Amazon) calls, such as `CreateFulfillmentOrder`.

> Following the previous question, would it be possible to receive shipping updates for products customers order through this non-Amazon seller website?

**Yes.** You can get at least some shipping and tracking information for FBA shipments from Amazon, see `GetPackageTrackingDetails`. I'm not sure if the included tracking number will always be valid - and this may very well depend on your country / region / other stuff. Depending on the level of detail you require, you might have to integrate with that shipping service's API as well.